# How to give Function Create/Delete/Alter/Execute permission while createing PostgreSQL user

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I want to give a Function Create/Delete/Alter/Execute permission to a user in PostgreSQL

While creating Function i'm getting this Error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: must be owner of function postgre_proc
```

This is my Procedure/Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION postgre_proc() 
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mapping_table_test VALUES (11, 'prasad', 24);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explainatory.

To be able to CREATE or REPLACE a function, you need to be owner of the function.

Using superuser, change ownership of function to the required user.

```
ALTER FUNCTION name ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [, ...] ] )
OWNER TO new_owner
```

Refer - [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-alterfunction.html)